# Pick Index of Array and group to new array by Index of Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary, indexing

I have an array, that each index will follow another index, and the index will not follow same index. After that index is current and index will be followed by index is target

This is code for python

```
list_value = [1,2,3]
for current in range(len(list_value)):
   for target in range(len(list_value)):

     if current == target: continue
     list_target.append(target)
```

expected output is `{current:0, target:[1,2,0,2,0,1]}`

but the result what i need is

```
{current:0, target:[1,2]}
{current:1, target:[0,2]}
{current:2, target:[0,1]}
```

I only add new target and repeatedly till the length of list_value done, I need help, please

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I believe what you want to do is this:

```
list_value = [1, 2, 3]
for current in range(len(list_value)):
    result = {"current": current, "target": []}
    for target in range(len(list_value)):
        if current != target:
            result["target"].append(target)
    print(result) # do something with each result here
```

This should print

```
{'current': 0, 'target': [1, 2]}
{'current': 1, 'target': [0, 2]}
{'current': 2, 'target': [0, 1]}
```

Comment: @Subhanshuja if this worked could you +1 it and accept it as the answer please

Comment: accept and i'm still new in stackoverflow, i cannot add +1